# Closures with arguments array of function

Tags: javascript

Taking a look at code from Leaflet API

Getting lost with arguments and closures.

My second log output of arguments is an empty array. Shouldn't be the same at the first log.

```js
limitExecByInterval: function (fn, time, context) {
    var lock, execOnUnlock;

    // Log output 1
    console.log(arguments);//[foo(), 10000, Window a.html]

    return function wrapperFn() {
        var args = arguments;

        if (lock) {
            execOnUnlock = true;
            return;
        }

        lock = true;

        setTimeout(function () {
            lock = false;

            if (execOnUnlock) {
                wrapperFn.apply(context, args);
                execOnUnlock = false;
            }
        }, time);

        //Log output 2
        console.log(args) //[]

        fn.apply(context, args);
    };
},
```

Comment: Arguments are different for the two functions..Thus different console log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't be the same at the first log.

No. Each function has its own `arguments` object. The second `console.log` call will log the arguments passed to `wrapperFn`, which doesn't seem to receive any in your test.

Answer (score 1):

This is because arguments is a keyword inside a function , and does not behave like normal variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

You would need to store arguments in another variable to get the desired behavior

```
limitExecByInterval: function (fn, time, context) {
        var lock, execOnUnlock;

        // Log output 1
        console.log(arguments);//[foo(), 10000, Window a.html]
        var myArgs = arguments ;

        return function wrapperFn() {
            var args = myArgs;  /* not using the keyword 'arguments' here */

            if (lock) {
                execOnUnlock = true;
                return;
            }

            lock = true;

            setTimeout(function () {
                lock = false;

                if (execOnUnlock) {
                    wrapperFn.apply(context, args);
                    execOnUnlock = false;
                }
            }, time);

            //Log output 2
            console.log(args) //[]  This will print an array now.

            fn.apply(context, args);
        };
    },
```